# Negative currency values using parse_number in readr R

Tags: r, currency, readr

I'm importing sales data that needs to be converted from character strings to numeric.

I'm trying to use `parse_number` in `readr` to do this, but it throws a parsing error for negative values, and coerces them to `NA`s.

As an example:

`x <- c("$1,000.00", "$500.00", "-$200.00")`

`y <- parse_number(x)`

`Warning: 1 parsing failure.
row # A tibble: 1 x 4 col     row   col expected actual expected   <int> <int> <chr>    <chr>  actual 1     3    NA a number -`

`y`

`[1] 1000  500   NA`

Does `parse_number` or `readr` have functionality that allows me to keep "-" for negative currency values?

(I'm not asking for an `as.numeric(gsub())` solution.)

Comment: I think if your data is already in this format, with negative before the currency symbol, it would be best to read in as character, remove the symbols and then use parse_number. Not sure why you are opposed to `as.numeric(gsub())` though

Comment: Yes, see my comment below.  I'm trying to keep our code consistent using tidyverse functions for readability and wanted to see if there was a `readr` solution, which it seems like there should be. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to stay with tidyverse functions as per [comment here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50164340/negative-currency-values-using-parse-number-in-readr-r#comment87346967_50164340) you can just use `stringr` functions instead of `gsub`. Options like this:

```r
library(tidyverse)
x <- c("$1,000.00", "$500.00", "-$200.00")
x %>%
  str_replace("^-\\$(.*)$", "$-\\1") %>%
  parse_number()
#> [1] 1000  500 -200

x %>%
  str_remove("\\$") %>%
  parse_number()
#> [1] 1000  500 -200
```

Created on 2018-05-03 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: Thanks.  The latter suggestion is clean and helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The use of currency symbol is wrong in your example. Try

```
library(readr)
x <- c("$1,000.00", "$500.00", "$-200.00")
parse_number(x)
#[1] 1000  500 -200
```

Since, problem is known, hence a simple solution can be using `gsub` as:

```
parse_number(gsub("\\$","",x))
#[1] 1000  500 -200
```

Comment: Thanks.  Unfortunately, the accounting program that we use outputs sales data in the way I used it in my example "-$200.00", which is obviously the root of the problem.  Apparently, I'll need to modify the vector first if I want to use `parse_number`.  It would be great if `parse_number` could handle both instances.

Comment: @AshLevitt I agree with your comments. But we need to check what is convention in other language. As you have already mentioned, as work-around , you can replace `-$` with `$-` and then convert.