# How to remove the characters from a string and leave only the numbers in R?

Tags: r

```r
a<- "\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\New\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t - \n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t95\n\t\t\t\tdays\n\t\t\t\n\t\t"
```

How to isolate only the number 95 from this string?
I tried the **gsub** and **str_replace** but it removes the 95 too
I removed this string from a site through the **rvest** package

Answer (score 2):

We can use `gsub` from `base R` to remove all characters that are not digits

```
gsub("\\D+", "", a)
#[1] "95"
```

Or as commented by @G Grothendieck

```
gsub("\\D", "", a)
```

---

Or with `str_remove_all`

```
library(stringr)
str_remove_all(a, "\\D+")
#[1] "95"
```

Answer (score 0):

The previous answers have approached the desired output negatively, by defining patterns for what is to be removed, namely anything that is *not* a number (hence `\\D` with uppercase D). Here's a positive solution defining what is to be kept, and extracting it via a self-defined function `extract`:

Define function, including the pattern to be matched `\\d{2}`(i.e., two contiguous numbers):

```
extract <- function(x) unlist(regmatches(x, gregexpr("\\d{2}", x, perl = T)))
```

Apply function to data `a`:

```
extract(a)
[1] "95"
```

Answer (score -1):

I was going to suggest to use `readr::parse_number` but then I learned that it will fail on the `-` charachter and then additional work is needed as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50164340/negative-currency-values-using-parse-number-in-readr-r).